# How to correctlly create mock http.request in golang for my test case?

Tags: go, routes

I want to write a test case to verify my parameter parser function.
The following is my sample code to mock a http.request

```
rawUrl := "http://localhost/search/content?query=test"

func createSearchRequest(rawUrl string) SearchRequest {
    api := NewWebService()

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", rawUrl, nil)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Fatal(err)
    }
    logger.Infof("%v", req)
    return api.searchRequest(req)
}
```

My web server use **github.com/gorilla/mux** as route

```
router := mux.NewRouter()

router.HandleFunc("/search/{query_type}", searchApiService.Search).Methods("GET")
```

But in my test case I cannot get `{query_type}` from mock `http.request`

```
func (api WebService) searchRequest(req *http.Request){
    // skip ....

    vars := mux.Vars(req)
    queryType := vars["query_type"]
    logger.Infof("queryType:%v", queryType)

    //skip ....
}
```

How can I get mux's path parameter in my test case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
func TestMaincaller(t *testing.T) {
    r,_ := http.NewRequest("GET", "hello/1", nil)
    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
   //create a map of variable and set it into mux
    vars := map[string]string{
    "parameter_name": "parametervalue",
    }

   r = mux.SetURLVars(r, vars)
  callfun(w,r)
}
```

Comment: Use `httptest.NewRequest` instead.